# Code for prime numbers adding to X working correctly but for multiple test cases at once, does not execute the last case until press enter

Tags: java, eclipse

I am giving all inputs in the starting of the code for t test cases.
It gives correct output for the t-1 test cases but does not gives the output for last test case until i press enter.
Due to this it's not getting accepted in the online portal.

I have tried the code in Eclipse where I found this issue.I have tried putting sc.next() instead of sc.nextInt() but the problem persists.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t-- > 0){
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            new GFG().findPrimesAddingToX(x);
        }
    }

    private void findPrimesAddingToX(int x){
        int p1 = 2;
        int p2 = 0;
        p2 = findPrime2(x);
        while(p1+p2 != x && p1 < p2){
            if(p1+p2 < x)
                p1 = findPrime1(p1);
            else if(p1+p2 > x)
                p2 = findPrime2(p2);
        }
        if(p1 + p2 == x)
            System.out.print("\n"+p1+" "+p2);
    }
    private int findPrime1(int p){
        boolean flag = false;
        while(!flag){
            flag = true;
            p++;
            for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(p); i++){
                if(p % i == 0){
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag){
                return p;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    private int findPrime2(int p){
        boolean flag = false;
        while(!flag){
            flag = true;
            p--;
            for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(p); i++){
                if(p % i == 0){
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag){
                return p;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```